# PostGIS Tiger Geocoder Not returning, stno, street, styp for geocoding

Tags: postgis, geocoding, tiger

I recently loaded TIGER 2018 data for California. After fixing all the errors I have loaded all the data into the database. I checked each of the tables and all of them contain data.

From this example
[How to make a PostGIS TIGER Geocoder in Less than 5 Days](https://experimentalcraft.wordpress.com/2017/11/01/how-to-make-a-postgis-tiger-geocoder-in-less-than-5-days/) 
I ran this query to check.

```
SELECT g.rating,
    ST_AsText(ST_SnapToGrid(g.geomout,0.00001)) As wktlonlat,
    (addy).address As stno,
    (addy).streetname As street,
    (addy).streettypeabbrev As styp,
    (addy).location As city,
    (addy).stateabbrev As st,(addy).zip
FROM geocode('424 3rd St, Davis, CA 95616',1) As g;
```

I get this result.

```
 rating |         wktlonlat          | stno | street | styp |    city     | st |  zip

 100    | POINT(-120.91795 38.29745) |      |        |      | Buena Vista | CA | 94502
```

As you can see the stno, street and styp are empty. I am not sure what the problem is as all the data has been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I recently went through the same tutorial and found that by default the nation_script does not load the ZCTA5 datasets, which the geocoder() stored procedure ultimately uses.  Run this query, then reload all the data (nation_script and state_scripts):

```
update tiger.loader_lookuptables
set load = 'true'
where lookup_name = 'zcta5_raw';
```

If that doesn't fix it you may have deeper issues.  It took me many days to get mine to work, mostly because I am not a DBA, just a normal user and did not have permissions for some of the actions the scripts take (create/drop schemas, drop tables, etc.)  If that is your situation, you'll also need to create your own versions of tables/stored procedures to get around the permissions issues.

Comment: I changed my postgres version to 10.6. Activated zcta. when you generate the scripts there would be some syntax errors in the code which can be easily fixed. I then ran the nation and state scripts for all the states. Everything is working smoothly now.

Answer (score 0):

Works smoothly with Postgres 10.6. Generates the nation and state scripts correctly. I ran it for all the states and haven't faced a problem.